# Unknown characters on Greek files on QGIS3

Tags: qgis

In the attribute table of the shapefile there are some weird characters instead of Greek ones. I tried UTF-8, Windows-1253, Greek and ISO-8857-9 when upload the shapefile on the QGIS 3.1.4. Although nothing seems to work.

Any other reccomendation?

Comment: You don't state the operating system in use, but the `od` utility of Unix fame, which has a Windows port, can tell you what exact bytes are present in th dBase file. From there you have to review codepages, looking for one where the bytes make sense. Or you can ask the source of the data for a UTF-8 encoded file.

Comment: This seems nearly the same question as from [yesterday](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372605/greek-characters-are-not-displayed-correctly-on-attribute-table-and-db-manager), though more information was provided then.

Comment: UTF-16 (UCS-2) is better for Greek http://www.stoa.org/unicode/encodings.html "UTF-16 is an encoding which represents all Basic Multilingual Plane characters (including basic Greek, extended Greek, and combining diacriticals) with two bytes and all other characters (including Aegean scripts, Etruscan, and any future scripts of relevance to classicists) with four bytes. The four-byte combinations use surrogates, two-byte .."

Comment: dBase is byte-oriented. I doubt that UTF-16 would work.